# Strange problems with the Spring RestTemplate in Android application

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, post

I began to use RESTful api of the Spring Framework in my android client application. But I have encountered with problems when I tried to execute HTTP request via postForObject/postForEntity methods. Here is my code:

```
public String _URL = "https://someservice/mobile/login";
public void  BeginAuthorization(View view)
{     
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
         HttpEntity<String> _entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
        templ.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        templ.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<String> _response = templ.postForEntity(_URL,_entity,String.class); //HERE APP CRASHES
        String _body = _response.getBody();
```

So the question what am I doing wrong? How to fix this? May there is other way to do it?

I really need a help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are targeting your app Android 4.0-4.2. Then you must perform all your operations in the background, not main (UI) thread. You are performing an authorization process, as I see. It's a short operation, so it's better for you to use `AsyncTask` for this. Here is howto for this on androidDevelopers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You should override doInBackground(Params...) in such a way:

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); 
        HttpEntity<String> _entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
        templ.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        templ.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<String> _response = templ.postForEntity(params[0],_entity,null) //null here in order there wasn't http converter errors because response type String and [text/html] for JSON are not compatible;
        String _body =  _response.getBody();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then call it in your BeginAuthorization(View view):

```
new LoginTask().execute(URL);
```

P.S. Also if you write Java please use correct naming conventions. Instead of this `_response` please write `response`.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html):

> **NetworkOnMainThreadException**
>
> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a
> networking operation on its main thread.

You should make a thread and do the networking from there. [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

from android>= 4.0 network calls must go through asynctack